# jQuery :checked, then add each chcked value to a string

Tags: jquery, each, checked

I have a form and I want the values of what has been checked to be outputted to the screen in a div. My code is ignoring the :checked part, it will output the value to a div when the checkbox is checked but it wont remove it when unchecked.

Also it isn't adding them to a list it is replacing the last clicked checkbox value with the old one...

Here is my code:

```
    jQuery('.detectChangeCheckbox').click(function(){

        jQuery(".detectChangeCheckbox").change(function () {

        var stepId = jQuery(this).attr("rel");

        var str = "You have selected: ";

        if(jQuery("detectChangeCheckbox:checked")){

            jQuery(this).each(function () {

                str += jQuery(this).val() + " ";

            });

        };

        jQuery("#liveResult"+stepId).text(str);

  })

  .change();

  });
```

Thanks

Comment: Get that `.change` method out of the `click` method.. Also, `jQuery("detectChangeCheckbox:checked")` is looking for a tag of `<detectChangeCheckbox>`

Comment: You dont need a .change inside a .click, it is the  same thing if you click it will register that it changed.

Comment: To add to the end instead of replacing using .append() instead of .text()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things - not sure why you have a `click` nested in a `.change` - don't do that unless you don't want your `change` event bound until after a click. I can only guess this is the code you want:

```
jQuery(".detectChangeCheckbox").change(function () {
    var stepID = jQuery(this).attr("rel");
    if (this.checked) {
        var checkedValues = jQuery(".detectChangeCheckbox:checked").map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get().join(" ");
        jQuery("#liveResult"+stepID).text(checkedValues);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Silly mistake missing the . class selector off the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be here in your if condition:

```
if(jQuery("detectChangeCheckbox:checked")){
```

here you have missed a `.` which is a css class selector representation in jQuery and you should check for length of checked instead:

```
if(jQuery(".detectChangeCheckbox:checked").length){
```

---

#### Note:

You don't need to have it wrapped with `click` handler, `change` event will do.

---

Instead i suggest you to do this:

```
jQuery(".detectChangeCheckbox").change(function () {
    var stepId = jQuery(this).attr("rel");
    var idx    = $(this).index();
    var arr    = [];
    ($(this).is(':checked')) ? arr.push(this.value) : arr.splice(1, idx);
    jQuery("#liveResult"+stepId).text(arr.join());
});
```